# How do i convert wav file to mp3 file if i have url of file using php?

Tags: php, mp3, wav, file-conversion

I have a url of the wav file  **http://xyz.com/recordings/employees/test.wav**

What i want to know is how can i change this file into mp3 format and store it in a particular location using php script because this file is located in some other server?

I know about ffmpeg but not sure whether it will work or not.

Comment: thanks cweiske for replying can you please tell me the code given on http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Php-ffmpeg will work on my web host (hostgator) also since it is shared hosting i have to ask them for installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an api which does this conversion process. The link for this is: [Api for conversion](http://api.online-convert.com/)

Answer (score 4):

I hope you have linux:

```
exec('wget http://xyz.com/recordings/employees/test.wav');
exec('ffmpeg -i test.wav test.mp3');
exec('mv test.mp3 /youlocation/test.mp3');
```

Comment: thanks thehorse for replying have to confirm from hosting provider?

Comment: if you use hosting with out root access you have to verify that your hoster have ffmpeg.

Comment: i had a talk with hosting provider i have to upgrade my account in order to execute the command. Can you please suggest whether there is any other library available for it which does not require commandline access.

Comment: i thikn there is no such liblary

Comment: ffmpeg is open source and can be build/distributed without needing to 'install' a package from your hosting provider if that is the problem. There are even static builds available if you don't have access to compilers...
https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

Thats usually no problem you may download this file to your webserver to a temporary folder. Than you have to convert it. There is e.g. a ffmpeg extension to php but not shipped with the php distribution afaik.

But even if you do not have this you can invoke a commandline on e.g a linux shell

```
ffmpeg -i /sometmpfolder/tmp.wav destination.mp3
```

Comment: thanks fyr for replying since i have shared hosting i think i have to confirm from them whether i can invoke commandline or not?

Comment: yes thats one option another one would be to check whether you have the extension installed/configured via phpinfo()

Comment: i have to upgrade my account to execute these commands. can you please suggest any other library which does not require command line access.