# Python convert wav to mp3

Tags: python, audio, mp3, wav

I've looked at pymedia (discontinued), pyglet(great but no converter in there) and audiotools(command line cd ripping), and none seem suitable.

In Python 2.7 , how do you do

```
convert(wavFileLocation, 'mp3')
```

If there is no python way, how would you do it in a manner which python can invoke? (e.g. Call a Cross platform command line tool... if exists return (name, pythonCodeForInvocation) )

Comment: which OS? Linux has some great command line utilities that would allow you to do this without much issue.

Comment: Linux =) But it needs to run on mac too

Comment: for linux, this solution gives you an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6578380/496405  use ffmpeg  should also work under mac :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

using [lame](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) (command line), you can encode wav to mp3 like this:

```
$ lame --preset insane /path/to/file.wav
```

which would create:

```
file.wav.mp3
```

in Python, you could use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) to call it:

```
wav = 'myfile.wav'
cmd = 'lame --preset insane %s' % wav
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: After hours of trying on-line methods to save audio in a compressed format like `mp3` or `ogg` from WAV-PCM data, this solution is the only one that have worked for me on Windows 10.

Answer (score 41):

I wrote a [python library, pydub](http://pydub.com), that essentially does what Corey's Answer suggests, though it uses ffmpeg in to do the conversions in order to support more formats.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

AudioSegment.from_wav("/input/file.wav").export("/output/file.mp3", format="mp3")
```

Comment: @Basj Not currently, no - you'd need to save the wav data to a file on disk, and then convert it to mp3 afterward. There has been some discussion about support for operating on steams/iterators, but nothing has come to fruition so far

Comment: This what worked for me: `song.export(mp3_path, format="mp3", codec="libmp3lame")`

Answer (score 12):

You must go for pydub, it is a great module for operations related with audio files.

NOTE. Do remember to install ffmpeg before you use pydub.

For help regarding installation of **ffmpeg**, you can use this [link](http://adaptivesamples.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/).

Then to install pydub just open your command prompt and type

```
pip install pydub
```

Then to convert any file from wav to mp3 just use **pydub** as

```
import pydub
sound = pydub.AudioSegment.from_wav("D:/example/apple.wav")
sound.export("D:/example/apple.mp3", format="mp3")
```

Answer (score -16):

will you can just rename the file extension , 
i think os library will help you any way i will give you example :

yourfile.wav ==>> yourfile.mp3 or any type that is for audio and video file

for me it's worked !!

Comment: If you rename it, there is only another name. But it is not really converted. A wav file is something different than a mp3 file, even if you name it like a mp3 file.